# reaction of structure

Tags: structures

all is this sturcture stable ? or structural determinate ?
[image]

Let the top support as A , bottom support as B ,

By taking moment about A, i managed to get 10(4*4)/2 -HA(2) = 0 , HA = 40kN,

HA = HB  = 40kN ,

By taking moment about C , i managed to get -10(4*4/2) + 4(VB + VA) -40(2) = 0

VA + VB = 40kN , however , i still not able to get the exact value of VA and VB, where did i miss out ?

Comment: is this structure in a single plane?  i.e. xz? It's difficult to tell from the drawing. Also is there an angle on the beam with the distributed load? Is the load uniform?

Answer (score 1):

The beam ac is a simply supported beam with uniformly distributed load of 40N so the reactions are

$$V_B=V_C=40/2\rightarrow V_B=20N$$

$$\Sigma V=40,\ V_A=20N$$